# Initializing non const reference with integer value

Tags: c++, reference

Please consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class test
{
    int& ref;
    public:
    test(int i):ref(i)
    {
        cout << "Constructor Called" << endl;
    }
    void p(){ cout<< ref << "\n";}
};

int main()
{
    test obj(5);
    obj.p();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Constructor Called
5
```

Doubt:
How is a non-const reference (ref) being initialized with an integer value (5) here, while the following code fails:

```
int& r = 5;
```

Comment: It's not being initialized with 5, it's being initialised with `i`. The call to `p()` is  UB.

Comment: [GCC 7.2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nvnMwDD1v9J7oQ9o) gives me a warning when I try to compile this: "warning: binding reference member 'ref' to stack allocated parameter 'i' [-Wdangling-field]".

Comment: `ref(i)` initializes `ref` with `i`, a local parameter that will be destroyed when `test` returns leaving you with a dangling reference.

Comment: Before, Correction, the compiler was Clang 5.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`test's` constructor:

```
test(int i)
```

takes an `int` as a parameter *by value*.

When you initialize the `obj` object by passing `5` to its constructor, i.e.:

```
test obj(5);
```

that constructor's parameter `i` is set to `5` (i.e.: `5` is copied into `i`), then the member reference `ref` is initialized with this parameter in the constructor member initializing list (and not the literal `5` used at constructor call):

```
test(int i):ref(i)
```

---

You have a *danging reference*: the reference `ref` outlives the referenced object (`i`), since the constructor's parameter `i` no longer exists once the constructor has returned.

Answer (score 4):

The reference is not being initialized with 5 directly, it is being initialized with the local `i`. Since `i` is destroyed upon the exit of the constructor, you are left with a [dangling reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Dangling_references), which is a reference that references an object that has gone out of scope. Compilers such as [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nvnMwDD1v9J7oQ9o) will tell you about this, with a warning that may be something like:

> warning: binding **reference** member 'ref' to stack allocated parameter 'i' [**-Wdangling-field**]